# how to get IEnumerable while using FindAsync

Tags: api, .net-core

how to get IEnumerable

looking for similar to which returns IEnumerable

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<EclSmsConfig>>> GetEclSmsConfig()
        {
            return await _context.EclSmsConfig.ToListAsync();
        }
```

how to get IEnumerable using below code in .net core 3.0 ?

```
public async Task<ActionResult<emp>> GetEclSmsConfig(int id)
        {
            var Emp = await _context.emp.FindAsync(id);
          
            if (Emp  == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Emp;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

below is working solution

```
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<emp>> Getemp(int id)
{

    IQueryable<emp> filterdata;

    if (id >= 1)
    {
         filterdata = from s in _context.emp
                         where (s.JobId == id)
                         select s;
    }
    else
    {
         filterdata = from s in _context.emp
                         select s;


    };

    var output = filterdata.ToArray();


    if (output.Length < 1)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return output;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be like below:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<EclSmsConfig>>> GetEclSmsConfig(int id)
{
    var result = await _context.emp.Where(e => e.Id == id).ToListAsync();

    if(!result.Any())
    {
        return NotFound()
    }

    return result;
}
```

If you are involving to develop your front-end, you should have refactoring to update front-end code to process with single record instead of require back-end api return a collection in case you are sure that is always has only one returned record.

Comment: yes, without IEnumerable I am not getting outer [ ] in the json, and getting error on Angular end (don't know how to solve that)